# Google Drive SDK Example - "DrEdit" ok on release build

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Has anyone run the Google Drive SDK Example - "DrEdit" ok on release build?
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android

I did it on debug build, but failed on release build.
I spent 2 days but always got error as follows:
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

*07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724):

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724): {

07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724):   "code": 403,

07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724):   "errors": [

07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724):     {

07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724):       "domain": "usageLimits",

07-24 17:27:55.295: W/System.err(21724):       "message": "Access Not Configured",

07-24 17:27:55.296: W/System.err(21724):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"

07-24 17:27:55.296: W/System.err(21724):     }

07-24 17:27:55.296: W/System.err(21724):   ],

07-24 17:27:55.296: W/System.err(21724):   "message": "Access Not Configured"

07-24 17:27:55.296: W/System.err(21724): }*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I've found the solution myself.

After clone codes of DrEdit from GitHub,

1. Change the package name
2. Follow everything on Google Drive SDK example website
3. In Eclipse, Clean all .jar and add what you needed manually.
4. In Eclipse, Make sure the file "project.properties" content it correct.

   4-A: the content is enabled:
   "proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt"

   4-B: the file "proguard-google-api-client.txt" is added into step 4-A
5. Add the following config into file "proguard-google-api-client.txt"

   -keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

   -keepclassmembers class * {
     @com.google.api.client.util.Key ;
   }

   -keep class com.google.** { *;}
   -keep interface com.google.** { *;}
   -dontwarn com.google.**

   -dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**

   -dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**

   -keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
   *;
   }
   -keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {
   *;
   }
6. Generate your own key by tool "Keytool", get SHA1 fingerprint , and use it on your Google API console
7. Make sure the setting on Google Console is set
8. Make sure the package name in "AndroidManifest.xml" is the same as Goolge Console

   [Ps.] For I'm still new here, so I don't have the right to upload image here.
      I will upload the screen capture later for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run on release mode, because the package, `com.example.android.notepad`, is registered to us  and you will not be able to authorize your application with your own signature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've changed the package name.